# Manipulate InputStream of ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: java, filter, jersey, jackson, dropwizard

I have a **encrypted string** being sent by a client. I am trying to intercept the string using **ContainerRequestFilter** then **decrypt** it and set the InputStream again so that it can be used by **Jackson** to map to a POJO.

Illustration:

My Resource

```
@Path("auth")
public class AuthResource {

@POST
public Response testResource(@Auth AuthUser auth, Person person) {

    System.out.println("Recieved Resource:: "+ new Gson().toJson(person));

    return null;
    }
}
```

Person.java

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person() {};

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

My Filter

```
@Provider
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override 
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        InputStream inputStream = requestContext.getEntityStream();

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer, "UTF-8");
        String theString = writer.toString();

        String decryptedMessage = "";
        try {
            decryptedMessage = JwtToken.decryptPayload(theString);
            System.err.println("Decrypted Message: "+decryptedMessage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(decryptedMessage.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        requestContext.setEntityStream(stream);
    }

}
```

I understand that once the InputStream is utilized it cannot be used again. But using **requestContext.setEntityStream(stream);** I am trying to set the InputStream again to be utilized by Jackson.

Inspite of that I am still **unable to get the person object in my resource**. The decryption is working fine as I have tested it using a debugger.

I get the following error: **415: Unsupported Media Type**

---

**Edit 1:** I am using Adavanced Rest Client to hit the url

http://localhost:8080/auth

**Header:**

```
authorization: Basic ZXlKaGRYUm9iM0pwZW1GMGFXOXVJam9pWVcxcGRDSXNJbUZzWnlJNklraFRNalUySW4wLmUzMC5MLUtmOUxQNjFSQ21Bektob2lTR0V4bEJ3RXRUMXhrR3A3bUpIZmFSeV9FOnBhc3M=
```

**Raw Payload:**

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiQW1pdCIsImFnZSI6MjJ9.-rO6yhYJ--3ZzVCaHFw1hF-s533foYY6vVAuyRh3Q9g
```

The payload is encrypted simply using JWT:

```
Jwts.builder().setPayload(new Gson().toJson(new  Person("Amit",22))).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, key).compact();
```

Comment: Please update your question with how you hit the URL. Are you doing a curl? Are you setting the headers to accept JSON as the request (defaults are plain text). Also ,your resource does not clarify what it is expecting (I think it defaults to json when you use jackson but that is just an assumption).

Comment: Try adding to your header: "Content-Type: application/json"

Comment: @pandaadb The Content-Type is set to text/plain. But I don't suppose that's the issue here. The issue is related to the InputStream I think.

Comment: @pandaadb after adding  "Content-Type: application/json" I get the following message: 400: Bad Request

Comment: Yes, so your first problem was the content type. Jackson can't parse plain text, only json/xml. This issue is now about your stream. What is the exception for the bad request

Comment: @pandaadb Yes you were right. The problem was in the "Content-Type". Resolved it in an unclean way. But it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your request payload is not a JSON. It's a JWT token which contains a JSON encoded as Base64. It's a piece of text. Hence, the `Content-Type` of the request should be `text/plain` instead of `application/json`:

```
POST /api/auth HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: text/plain

eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiQW1pdCIsImFnZSI6MjJ9.-rO6yhYJ--3ZzVCaHFw1hF-s533foYY6vVAuyRh3Q9g
```

Your filter modifies the payload of the request: the filter gets the JWT token from the request payload, gets the token payload, decodes the token payload into a JSON string and sets the JSON string to the request payload.

After the executing of the filter, the request will contain a JSON string and not just a piece of text. Hence, after that, the `Content-Type` of the request should be modified to `application/json`. It could be achieved with the following lines:

```java
requestContext.getHeaders().remove(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE);
requestContext.getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

To ensure the filter will be executed before the resource matching, annotate your filter with [`@PreMatching`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/PreMatching.html).

And don't forget to annotate your resource method with `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`.

Comment: Thanks! You are correct. My way was quite messy. Yours is more cleaner. Will update my code.

Comment: Yep - this seems correct. I was not aware of JwtTokens and thought this was an invention of yours :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing the payload to a JSON document as:

```
"temp":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiQW1pdCIsImFnZSI6MjJ9.-rO6yhYJ--3ZzVCaHFw1hF-s533foYY6vVAuyRh3Q9g"
```

and extracted the encrypted payload using the below code in my filter:

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(theString, JsonObject.class);
        theString = jsonObject.get("temp").getAsString();
```

Also changed the resource to **@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)**

And it worked!

I guess the reason was as mentioned by [pandaadb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2704500/pandaadb) that Jersey was unable to recognize it as a JSON document and hence was unable to Map it to the Person POJO.

Comment: If you are sending a JWT in the payload, the `Content-Type` of the request should be `text/plain` and not `application/json`. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38829866/1426227) for clarification.